# Complex torus as group

Tags: group-theory

There is a relation between discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, periodic functions and circular group $\mathbb{T}$ (as set is the circle $S^1$).
For exemple the periodic function $\varphi: t\in \mathbb{R}\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}\in \mathbb{T}$ is a homomorphism with $Ker\phi=\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}\simeq\mathbb{T}$.

There is a relation also between complex lattices of $\mathbb{C}$, double-periodic functions (i.e. elliptic functions) and complex torus (that is, as topological space the torus $S^1\times S^1)$.

The complex torus is a group of type $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{C}}{\Lambda}$ where $\Lambda=\{n\omega_1+m\omega_2:n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a complex lattice of $\mathbb{C}$.
I ask what is the structure of a complex torus as group? My idea is that $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{C}}{\Lambda}\simeq \mathbb{T}\oplus\mathbb{T}$.
Can someone please help me to construct a explicit isomorphism?

Ps. The complex torus is a  compact Lie group of dimension 1 and a structure theorem said that as group it's isomorphic to direct sum of $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: "A complex torus $\Bbb T^n$ is a connected compact $n$-dimensional complex manifold with complex analytic group structure (namely an abelian compact complex Lie group)." You ask about the group structure? For a very detailed explanation see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_torus).

Comment: For example if i consider the Gaussian lattice $\mathbb{Z}\oplus i\mathbb{Z}$ or the Eisenstein lattice $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \omega\mathbb{Z}$ ($\omega=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$) then the corrispondent complex torus (as group) to what it's isomorphic?

Comment: As you said, to $\Bbb T^2$. Consider a fundamental domain glued together at opposite sides to give this torus.